# What's the best way to send multiple commands via ssh whilst running a script?

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm making a script that occasionally sends commands to another machine over ssh. At the moment, im just calling this one function that opens up a new shell for each command it sends like so:

```
 #!/bin/bash

port='22'
user='user'
host='hostname'

send_ssh() {
        ssh -oBatchMode=yes -oConnectTimeout=5 -p "$1" -tq "$2"@"$3" "$4" || exit 1
}

send_ssh "$port" "$user" "$host" true
   # it worked so do some stuff locally blah blah

send_ssh "$port" "$user" "$host" anothercommand
   # rest of script
```

I've looked at keeping a tunnel open in the background and / or using a control socket so i can speed things up without having to open a new connection for each command but cant work out if and wether it's worth doing that in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up a control socket is so easy that I would argue it is absolutely worth doing, even with only two calls to `send_ssh`.

```
send_ssh() {
    ssh -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=10 -oBatchMode=yes -oConnectTimeout=5 -p "$1" -tq "$2"@"$3" "$4" || exit 1
}
```

`ControlMaster=auto` means that an existing connection will be used if available, otherwise one will be opened for you.

The setting `ControlPersist=10` means that the connection to the remote host will remain open for 10 seconds after the client exists, you can adjust this as desired. You can set it to `0` or `yes` to keep it open permanently, in which case you'll want to make sure something like

```
ssh -o exit -p "$1" "$2@$3"
```

executes before your script exits to close the master connection.

Comment: I think it's cautious to set ControlPath with ControlPersist set to 0.

Comment: That's probably a good idea regardless of the value of `ControlPersist`.